# Why my object detection output gives wrong names?

Tags: python, machine-learning, image-processing, deep-learning, computer-vision

I am new in machine vision and i was trying to detect objects. I watched a YouTube video and i did exactly what the teacher did! He tried the code for car and person and also the only true output is related to pictures of car and person but i want to use it to detect fruits.

[image] [image]

Also the code is:

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

config_file = "ssd_mobilenet_v3_large_coco_2020_01_14.pbtxt"
frozen_model = "frozen_inference_graph.pb"

model = cv2.dnn_DetectionModel(frozen_model, config_file)

classlabels = []
file_name = 'labels.txt'
with open(file_name, 'rt') as fpt:
    classlabels = fpt.read().rstrip('\n').split('\n')

model.setInputSize(320,320)
model.setInputScale(1.0/127.5)
model.setInputMean((127.5,127.5,127.5))
model.setInputSwapRB(True)


# Read the image

img = cv2.imread('person.jpg')

ClassIndex, confidence, bbox = model.detect(img, confThreshold=0.5)
print(ClassIndex)

font_scale = 3
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN
for ClassInd, conf, boxes in zip(ClassIndex.flatten(), confidence.flatten(), bbox):
    cv2.rectangle(img,boxes,(255,0,0),2)
    cv2.putText(img,classlabels[ClassInd-1],(boxes[0]+10,boxes[1]+40), font, fontScale=font_scale,color=(0,255,0), thickness=3)

plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
plt.show()
```

The ssd_mobilenet_v3_large_coco_2020_01_14.pbtxt link: https://gist.github.com/dkurt/54a8e8b51beb3bd3f770b79e56927bd7

Coco names link: https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet/blob/master/data/coco.names

frozen_inference_graph.pb link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/19seKEz-HYBkY_4DZV9ieu4gxgOnPxqhs/view

Comment: "also the only true output is related to pictures of car and person but i want to use it to detect fruits" - could you elaborate what you mean on this part?

Comment: It only gives correct answers to pictures of people and cars. As I have specified in the photo, the answer of the program to the photo of the apple is wrong. @AndW

Comment: Does this behavior persist when you try other fruit images, or maybe the same image multiple times?

Comment: I tried many different pictures of different fruits. I also tried the picture of the chair that was in coco names, but they all give wrong answers. @AndW